# MmFile Empty Files throws Exception in Destructor

Tags: exception, scope, d, mmap

I'm having trouble getting `MmFile` to work in a directory scanning algorithm.

When I'm stress-testing it as follows

```
foreach (dent; dirEntries(..)) {
    const size_t K = ...;
    const ulong size = ...;
    scope auto mf = new MmFile(dent.name, MmFile.Mode.read, size, null, win)  
}
```

I can't find a combination of `size` and `win` that works for all cases when reading data.

When I set

```
const size = 0;
const win = 64*1024;
```

the length gets calculated correctly.

But when `dent.name` is an existing *empty* file it crashes in the destruction of the `MMFile` throwing a

```
 core.exception.FinalizeError...std.exception.ErrnoException@std.mmfile.d(490): munmap failed (Invalid argument).
```

And I can't recover this error by catching `core.exception.FinalizeError` because its thrown in the destructor. I haven't tried

```
try { delete mm; } catch (core.exception.FinalizeError) { ; /* pass */}
```

Maybe that works.

Is this the default behavior when calling `mmap` in C on existing empty files?

If so I think that MmFile should check for this error during construction.

The except gets thrown also when I replace `scope` with an explicit `delete`.

For now I simply skip calling `MmFile` on empty files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a bug to me for `MmFile` to barf on empty files regardless of what `mmap` itself does. [Please report it](http://d.puremagic.com/issues).

On a side note, I'd advise against using either `scope` or `delete`, as they're going to be removed from the language, because they're both unsafe. [std.typecons.scoped](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_typecons.html#scoped) replaces `scope` in this context if you want to do that (though it's still unsafe). And as for `delete`, `destroy` will destroy the object without freeing its memory, and `core.memory` can be used to free memory if you *really* want to, but in general, if you want to be worrying about freeing memory, then you should be manually managing your memory (with `malloc` and `free` and possibly `emplace`) and not using the GC at all.